# Ubuntu 14.04 installer has an invisible cursor

Tags: cursor

When trying to install Ubuntu via a bootable USB drive, the cursor is missing in the installer. It's there for a few seconds, when loading it. But after that it's gone, I have to click a few buttons but I can't without a cursor! How do I fix this, since there is absolutely no Terminal or options screen or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can click buttons using tab and then spacebar on the keyboard.